# Accessing parent objects while using a javascript module pattern variant

Tags: javascript, class, object, design-patterns, parent

Hi I'm using this module pattern variant and I'm looking for the best way to get access to a parent object. I realise there is no way to know what parents an object has so I want to include some context in the constructor. I thought this would work but it doesn't, any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var main = new Main();

});


function Main() {

    var one = 'hello';

    init();

    function init() {
        var data = new Data(this);
        var two = data.load();
        console.log(one+' '+two);
        data.output();
    }

}

function Data(context) {

    // public vars / methods

    var pub = {
        'load' : function() {
            return ('world');
        },
        'output' : function() {
            var one = context.one // <-- what should this be?
            var two = this.load();
            console.log (one+' '+two);
        }
    }

    return pub;

}
```

The output is:

```
hello world
undefined world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a constructor function with the `new` operator, you are basically doing something like

```
function Main(){
    var this = //magic new object
               //provided by the runtime

    //your code comes here

    return this;
    //because your Data function returns a value,
    // you never get to this line. Perhaps you should use
    // a regular non-constructor data() function instead?
}
```

When you declare a private variable with `var` it will just be a plain variable and nothing else. If you want to add things to the `this` you need to do so explicitely

```
this.one = 'hello';
```

But that is not all! `this` is *not* lexically scoped so the init function gets its own other `this` that is unrelated to the `this` from outside (this explains the `undefined` you get). When you want to use `this` in an inner function you need to do a workaround, like in:

```
var that = this;

function init(){
    new Data(that);
}
init();
```

---

That said, just by your example I don't see why you need to do all of this. I prefer to use constructor functions (and `new`) only when strictly necessary (when I want to make use of prototypal inheritance). In your case perhaps you can get away with a "less OO" approach?

```
//main doesn't need to be a class
// this is not Java :)
function main(){

    //just a plain object for the 
    //context. Create a separate class
    //if you really need to...
    var context = {
        one: 'hello'
    };

    var data = new Data(context);
    var two = data.load();
    console.log(one+' '+two);
    data.output();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very clear and just what I was after. I agree my example does not need the added complexity, I just made it as simple as possible to demonstrate the pattern. Thanks again!